# How to solve $E((X+1)^2)$ if $X$ follows a Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, poisson-distribution

Assume that a policyholder is five times more likely to file exactly four claims as to file exactly two claims. Assume also that the number $X$ of claims of this policyholder is Poisson. Determine the expectation $E((X+1)^2)$.

I solve for Poisson and got $\lambda=\sqrt{60}$ but don't really understand where to go from there.

Comment: $E((X+1)^2) = Var(X) + [E(X)+1]^2$. Do you know the formula for the variance of a Poisson random variable? Also mention how you got $\lambda = \sqrt{60}$.

Comment: P(x=4)=5P(x=2) and then plug in the formula for Poisson on both sides. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the linearity of the expectation, plus the facts that $Var(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$ and, for the Poisson distribution, $Var(X)=E[X]=\lambda$:

$$
E[(X+1)^2]=E[X^2]+2E[X]+1=Var(X)+E[X]^2+2E[X]+1=\lambda^2+3\lambda+1
$$

Comment: did you mean lambda^2+2lambda+1?

Comment: No. I meant $\lambda^2+3\lambda+1$ because $Var(X)=\lambda$ too.